# Do duplicants passing through a park in a pneumatic tube get the morale boost?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

Pretty much what it says in the title. Morale management is an important factor in mid-and lategame, and [Parks and Nature Reserves](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Room_Overlay#Rooms) are pretty beefy morale boosters to Duplicants passing through them.

However, since finding a good spot for them is very RNG-dependent and forcing pathfinding to pass through them can be a hassle or cut drastically into commute times, I'm wondering if it's viable to build a pneumatic tube that passes through the designated park area and still grants the morale bonus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To my surprise, the answer is: **yes**!

[image]